# C# close StreamWriter

Tags: c#

Im trying to close a text file that I have created and then read this back into a HTMLDocumentClass.

This is the code

```
StreamWriter outfile = 
    new StreamWriter(StripHTMLComps.Properties.Settings.Default.TempFileName);
outfile.Write(HTML);
outfile.Close();

HTMLDocumentClass doc = null;
doc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
IPersistFile persistFile = (IPersistFile)doc;
persistFile.Load(StripHTMLComps.Properties.Settings.Default.TempFileName, 0);
GC.SuppressFinalize(persistFile);
int start = Environment.TickCount;
while (doc.readyState != "complete")
{
    if (Environment.TickCount - start > 10000)
    {
    }
}
```

The document says loading but never completes, I believe that it believes the document is still in being used by another process.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your while loop supposed to do? Wait until something is done? Because right now, it's not really 'waiting' now is it?

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the creation of the string in a `using` statement to ensure proper disposal (part of which will release the file handle - thanks @Adam Houldsworth):

```
using(StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(StripHTMLComps.Properties.Settings.Default.TempFileName))
{
   outfile.Write(HTML);
   // outfile.Close(); // not needed, as the disposal will close the file.
}

// read the file now
```

Comment: Still having the same issue                                      using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(StripHTMLComps.Properties.Settings.Default.TempFileName))
                {
                    outfile.Write(HTML);
                    outfile.Close();
                }

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question and should have been a comment or  a side note on a real answer. Also, only the html write code should go in the using i think, not the rest of the code

Comment: @steven, no need to explicitly close the stream in a using statement, it will be done automatically. I would also suggest you step through your code in debug mode

Answer (score 2):

I believe the HTMLDocumentClass is from the WebBrowser.

I'm not sure you can use without the browser control, but if you can, you do not give it CPU cycles to process the file.

Try adding an `Application.DoEvents` or `Sleep` somewhere.

If that does not work, add a WebBrowser to your form, make it load the html, and use the object the browser exposes.

If you are just interested in parsing the html tree, look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The code is written inside a DLL that is called from another 3rd party application.

Answer (score 0):

Too many assumptions in there for me

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(SomeName,...))
{
  StreamWriter s = new Streamwriter(fs);
  s.Write(HTML);
  s.Flush();
}
```

Now it should be okay to use. I have a policy of always opening / creating files with FileStream using explicit permission requests. If somethings not right you want that bit to fall over, not some code twenty minutes later and ten yards deeper in.
The other thing to think about is why you need HTMLDocumentClass, it's a helper wrapper for a com object for use in a web browser control, and chock full of weirdness.

Can't confirm this, but I saw a report that in order to get the doc state to completed, you had to call DoEvents inside your while not completed loop.

[Somebody else witha similar issue](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToLoadHTMLIntoMshtmlHTMLDocumentClassWithUCOMIPersistFileAndMyIgnorance.aspx)